# How to call CreateProcess() in C# passing lpEnvironment

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, environment-variables, clr

I imported native CreateProcess into my C# project
for ICorDebug purposes http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms232508(v=vs.100).aspx

```
 [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void CreateProcess([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpApplicationName, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpCommandLine, [In] SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes, [In] SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, [In] int bInheritHandles, [In] uint dwCreationFlags, [In] IntPtr lpEnvironment, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpCurrentDirectory, [In] STARTUPINFO pStartupInfo, [In] PROCESS_INFORMATION pProcessInformation, [In] CorDebugCreateProcessFlags debuggingFlags, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out ICorDebugProcess ppProcess);
```

I call it trying to pass lpEnvironment this way

```
            IntPtr intPtrEnv;
            if (variables != string.Empty)
                intPtrEnv = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(variables);
            else
                intPtrEnv = new IntPtr(0);

 p_codebugger.CreateProcess(
                                exepath,
                                exepath,
                                null,
                                null,
                                1, // inherit handles
                                (UInt32)CreateProcessFlags.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
                                intPtrEnv,
                                ".",
                                si,
                                pi,
                                CorDebugCreateProcessFlags.DEBUG_NO_SPECIAL_OPTIONS,
                                out proc);
```

the variables string contains:

```
"COR_ENABLE_PROFILING=1\0COR_PROFILER=PROFILER_GUID\0COR_PROFILER_PATH=GetProfilerFullPat\0\0"
```

I GET an ERROR
 Value Exceeded Allowable Range

Any suggestions how to pass the environment block from c# into the c++ dll?

Comment: formatting your question may help to get better answers...

Comment: Pass null for the current dir. Why do you pass exepath twice? Where are si and pi initialised? Your environment has three nulls at the end, one of them implicit. You only need two. Where's the rest of the env string. You need more env vars than that surely.

Comment: let me put it that way. All works perfectly when i pass IntPtr.Zero instead of env string.

Comment: But you just threw away all the rest of the default environment. Did you mean to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok i managed to resolve my problem. 
First i used StringBuilder instead of IntPtr.
To add a string `"COR_ENABLE_PROFILING=1\0COR_PROFILER=PROFILER_GUID\0COR_PROFILER_PATH=GetProfilerFullPat\0\0"`
i simply add("COR_ENABLE_PROFILING=1") and the increse the Stringbuilder lenght + 1 etc...;
the end should be incremented one more time lenght++ (this is the ansi encoding); 
Second thing is to change and add marshalling into the imported method
Instead of [`In] IntPtr lpEnvironment` add `[In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder lpEnvironment`

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use P/Invoke for this, you can use the .Net [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx) method directly from your C# code.

If you want to customize the process startup, pass environment variables etc, use one of the overloads that takes a [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) object.

Comment: maybe, but im am using ICorDebug interface. And to make that work(capture debug events) immediatly after process creation i need to use the create method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/ms232508(v=vs.110).aspx